# How to search a list on multiple columns?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a temp table with multiple items.

I want to search multiple columns in a second table to get the rows which has this items but with the LIKE Function:

For example

```
#list = temp table with items 

SELECT *
FROM table2 
WHERE 
    ID like %#list%
 OR Name like %#list%
 OR Adress like %#list%
```

Is this possible with TSQL?

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for ~30 months. It is *long* past time you had your upgrade path sorted by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use an `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM #List L
              WHERE t2.ID LIKE CONCAT('%',L.Item,'%') --Assumes ID is a string based data type
                 OR t2.Name LIKE CONCAT('%',L.Item,'%')
                 OR t2.Adress LIKE CONCAT('%',L.Item,'%')); --Address has 2 d's
```

Comment: Could work, but looks very complicated

Comment: I, personally, wouldn't say it is, @PeterXO . It's literally just an `EXISTS` with 3 `LIKE` clauses. There are far more complicated things out there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer.

Put the strings you want to look after in a #temp table
with '%text1%'

| items |
| --- |
| %text1% |
| %text2% |

Then use JOINs for searching like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN #temp
  ON table_1.column1 like #temp.items
  OR table_1.column2 like #temp.items
```

...

I think it works well

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You can't use `LIKE` on a table.

Comment: but its works. with TSQL

Comment: Now that you've changed it from `LIKE #temp` to `#temp.column_1` yes. Note that you could get multiple of the same row with this solution.

Comment: You right. If i have in the same cell text1 and text2 than its douple the row. right?

Comment: It would. Or if column1 matched one row, and column2 another. This is one reason why I used an `EXISTS` in my answer